# Why does this import code work in Visual Studio Code but not IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

**File Structure**

```
Main Folder

Program.py

Module_Folder
     MODULE_1.py
     MODULE_2.py
     MODULE_3.py
```

In "Program.py" I am using the following line to import MODULE_1 into Program.py: "from Module_Folder import MODULE_1 as MODULE_1"
This works in visual studio code but not in IDLE. Could someone advise me on what to change for this to work in IDLE?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add an `__init__.py` file to your `Module_Folder`, so Python would know it's a package. You cannot simply import files from folders, if they don't have `__init__.py`